# Excel SQL Query Using VBA on Mac OSx?

Tags: vba, macos, excel, odbc, dao

**Excel for Windows** - 
Based on DAO, I’ve developed a VBA user defined function (UDF) returning a single numerical value from an Access database based on parameters.

*e.g. GetValue(Entity, Department, Period, Account#)*

**Excel for Mac OSX** -
I discovered that DAO and ADO libraries / functionalities are not available on Excel 2016 for Mac OSX :(

Is there a way to develop the same VBA UDF that would connect to the Access DB via ODBC and run a SQL query to retrieve the desired value, i.e. GetValue(Entity, Department, Period, Account#)?

Thank you for your kind support!
Chris